# Create compiler error on different type check (tsconfig)

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain why this is not throwing an error?

```
interface A {
    id?: number;
}
const a:A = {
    id: 5
};
const testA: boolean = (a === 1); //works, but why?


interface B {
    id: number;
}
const b:B = {
    id: 5
};
const testB: boolean = (b === 1); //compiler error -> expected that also on A
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+cAEwH4AuZEAVwFsAjaAbiwF8sEB7EAZzGThPQC8mHHkJkArM0bsuPSN1RkabNgBsIcEMiEAKONoFCAjAEp6yAPQWA7mygBrTgBpkNCj2sALAJ5Es-0EhYRBQAIWE8fAIySloGZlYOblcScKFsSLFkSSZpJLkIblClFXVNbWQdGgNjM0sLdioAB2B1KGRoKDtkAFoAPg6ADyaIBEgCZDBPOB44VU42ZA40fyA)

Comment: Why shouldn't it be allowed ? That's a comparison operator, which will yield false here, but if you want to get an error each time a comparison like this is reached, you'll probably need to write your own "compare" method and call it in place of `===` operator.

Comment: @Mozgor this is a comparison that never fulfils, hence it's a mistake. So the OP has a perfectly valid request.

Comment: You can tell it will never fullfill, but I don't know how transpiler could, except if the actual question is "prevent comparison between *const* of different types".

Comment: The compiler can tell it for sure: types of the `foo` and `1` are incompatible.

Comment: This shows an error in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=8&pln=4&pc=5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeCQC4YEYC+A3AFDECWcAFJisqrgJTowD0LMUAFmRDBJyACuAGwAmYAOSwARgFMYAQ2HCQAd1miYxGDq34gA . Do you not want an error ? Or are you not getting an error, and if so what version and what tsconfig ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir oh wow, it was one of that moments I trusted the OP and didn't check the thing myself 

Comment: @seryoga This shows an error already...so it is not allowed. What do you want?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  Your right i wondering why its not woking in my angular app like in your example

Comment: Im updatet my answer and i don't get an error now. But when i remove optional ? from group i get it...

Comment: @Seryoga `A` is a weak type, in theory under structural type rules, any other type would be assignable to `A` , TS does an extra check to see if there are no common properties between the types and we do get an error on absurd assignments. The lack of an error in the case of comparison, might be an oversight, or an intentional inconsistency in the name of usability... You would have to search GH to see if there are similar issues and if not I would report it as a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's examine this behavior:

```
let foo: { foo?: number } = { foo: 1 };
foo = 1; // error, no common properties
foo === 1; // okay
```

In TypeScript 2.4 and above, the assignment fails because the type of `foo` is a [weak type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) (all properties are optional, like `Partial<Something>`) with no properties in common with `number`.  By the normal rules of structural compatibility (before TS2.4), this assignment should *succeed*, because as long as a `number` doesn't have *any* property named `foo`, there's no incompatibility... at runtime `(1).foo` is `undefined`, and `undefined` is one of the things you expect when reading `foo` from `{foo?: number}`.  But this was a potential source of bugs, so TS2.4 introduced weak type detection to catch them; that is, the language made weak type incompatibility prevent *assignability*.

The comparison succeeds, however, because *comparability* is not prevented by weak type incompatibility.  The two types are still considered comparable.  Why?  Well, I'm not sure what the motivation is, but I can see that it's at least intentional.  There was, at one point, a push to update the moldering [TypeScript spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md).  I think they have given up on such an update (the language is changing too quickly and they don't have enough resources to constantly work on the spec, the upshot of this is that in order to understand the current language you need to keep reading release notes, GitHub issues, and even source code), but I see that one of the non-merged pull requests, [microsoft/TypeScript#17215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17215), provided details about comparability.  [Specifically](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17215/commits/e2e20bd6f810dd210f641794ab6a46e0d98eb0a4#diff-a37bdfbd0d2f3627958003f87033871eR2396):

> whether a type is considered weak has no bearing on whether two types are comparable

So there you go.  Comparability ignores weakness of the types, so you are allowed to compare `{foo?: number}` with `number`.  It's intentional, although again, not sure why.

I guess you (or someone else) filed [microsoft/TypeScript#36602](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36602) to ask about this.  The important question to ask here if we want to imagine changing this is: what real-world TypeScript code would break if we tightened this.  If it's a lot, and most of those breakages are not catching legitimate bugs, then there's a very low chance this will change.  Even if it only improves things in terms of bug-finding, it might degrade compiler performance too much to be worth it.  The only way to be sure is for the TS team to agree to consider a pull request for this change.  And I'm not on that team so ‍♂️.

---

Finally, let's just contrast the previous code with slight changes to make sure we understand the difference between non-overlapping weak types, non-overlapping non-weak types, and overlapping weak types:

Here's a non-overlapping non-weak type:

```
let bar: { bar: number } = { bar: 1 };
bar = 1; // error, not assignable
bar === 1; // error, not comparable
```

Both assignment and comparison fail; the types are not structurally compatible.  And here's an overlapping weak type:

```
let baz: { toFixed?(): string } = { toFixed: () => "" };
baz = 1; // okay
baz === 1; // okay
```

Both assignment and comparison succeed; since `number` has a `toFixed()` method that returns a `string`, (well, `Number` has it, and `number` is coerced to `Number` when you access its members) the type `{toFixed?(): string}` is a weak type that overlaps `number`.

---

Okay, hope that helps makes sense of the behavior.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEDe04H5EDsCuBbARiAE4QC+EAvMqghAIxkDcAULDJfYxAPTcTFEYRADQRM7AMYxcuGJggAHQQuJgAliADOrOJQpU6XXhBgBrAIYBPZs1CR85oohQOnYvIRLkqLx4gakLK4chjx8AkKi4pDmmppqAOaY5vigzMH6BkbhRIIiYjCQUrgKjimgEDZ2EA4AXs4QYDAAYmoAHiAAJmgAFACUiJpgRGqYCWQcKE2tHZ2I-ZQAfBAARCtM6ea1IdkmFtZ1ellhe1Y2QA)

Comment: They could extend the tsconfig with an option so older code wouldn't break

Answer (score 1):

```
interface A {
    id?: number;
}
```

Declaration of interface with only optional properties is declaring a weak type.

And weak type has some weird behaviour.

It ignores the Comparability, so you are allowed to compare {foo?: number} with a number.

```
const a: A = {id:1}
a === 1
```

But still, it's a question of why this is allowed.

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account [weak type detection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) introduced in TS 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Weak-types have "weird" behaviour because basically the only thing you know for certain about it is that they are an object. And in javascript, *almost everything* is an object, which means something like this is possible:

```
type foo = {}
declare let c: foo

c = 1
```

Numbers can be created with the `Number` constructor after-all, so the operation is technically type-safe. (Repl link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nKBeKBvAvgKEwEwgYwBsBDAJ2kImCnwC5YFt9koBGIA))

The solution is to add at-least one key in the object that's not optional, at which point you've given typescript enough information to distinguish between two objects.