# Why does TypeScript type inference fail in this case?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to understand why type `S1` is `never`, but when I remove the `label` or `customRef` properties I get correct result of `string`. When I remove the `value` and `label` properties I get `unknown`.

```
export interface BaseInputProps<TStored> {
  value: TStored;
  customRef?: (selfProps: this) => void;
}

export interface TestInput extends BaseInputProps<string> {
  label: string;
}

type InferStoredType<T> = T extends BaseInputProps<infer TT> ? TT : never;

type S1 = InferStoredType<TestInput>;
```

What is happening here?

Typescript version 3.7.5. Works the same way on the Typescript playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the structural difference and [weak type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection). So let's understand your problem in all the cases

**Case 1: By default, it is never**

> When you try to extend `interface TestInput` with `interface BaseInputProps<string>` it will
>   *try to check if all the properties typing are compatible* but in this case `customRef?: (selfProps: this) => void;` type `(selfProps: this)=> void` is not assignable to `string` and vice versa. That's why it is falsy inheritance because of which S1 is `never`

**Case 2: When you remove label and customRef, it is string**

> When you removed label and customRef `interface BaseInputProps` and `interface TestInput` will be left out with one compulsory property `value` because of which it will correctly infer the typings.

**Case 3: When you remove value and label, it is unkown**

> When you removed the value and label `interface BaseInputProps` and
>   `interface TestInput` will be left out with only optional property and
>   typescript can't guarantee the typings in this case.

Still, why this change was intentional is a question. But, looking at the scope of the spec change it will involve, I guess it's very difficult to see a change in this.

Please read this too for more on [weak typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054313/create-compiler-error-on-different-type-check-tsconfig) and on [conditional typings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html).

Comment: Still I don't get why is it `never` in the first case?

Comment: @HristoKolev Updated answer for first default case.

Comment: " type (selfProps: this)=> void is not assignable to string and vice versa." But why would that be checked? They have different names, these properties have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Both the interface has to be structurally the same for `T extends BaseInputProps<infer TT>` to be true.

Comment: I'm interpreting this as 'if T implements BaseInputProps of somethig, give me the something'. Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly I mean since BaseInputProps has optional properties then T need to have optional property too. Otherwise, both are structurally different